# How can I do map reduce on spark dataframe group by conditional columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, mapreduce

My spark dataframe looks like this:

```
+------+------+-------+------+
|userid|useid1|userid2|score |
+------+------+-------+------+
|23    |null  |dsad   |3     |
|11    |44    |null   |4     |
|231   |null  |temp   |5     |
|231   |null  |temp   |2     |
+------+------+-------+------+
```

I want to do the calculation for each pair of userid and useid1/userid2 (whichever is not null).

And if it's useid1, I multiply the score by 5, if it's userid2, I multiply the score by 3.

Finally, I want to add all score for each pair.

The result should be:

```
+------+--------+-----------+
|userid|useid1/2|final score|
+------+--------+-----------+
|23    |dsad    |9          |
|11    |44      |20         |
|231   |temp    |21         |
+------+------+-------------+
```

How can I do this?

For the `groupBy` part, I know dataframe has the `groupBy` function, but I don't know if I can use it conditionally, like if userid1 is null, `groupby(userid, userid2)`, if userid2 is null, `groupby(userid, useid1)`.

For the calculation part, how to multiply 3 or 5 based on the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below solution will help to solve your problem.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val groupByUserWinFun = Window.partitionBy("userid","useid1/2")
  val finalScoreDF = userDF.withColumn("useid1/2", when($"userid1".isNull, $"userid2").otherwise($"userid1"))
    .withColumn("finalscore", when($"userid1".isNull, $"score" * 3).otherwise($"score" * 5))
    .withColumn("finalscore", sum("finalscore").over(groupByUserWinFun))
    .select("userid", "useid1/2", "finalscore").distinct()
```

using `when` method in spark SQL, select userid1 or 2 and multiply with values based on the condition

Output:

```
+------+--------+----------+
|userid|useid1/2|finalscore|
+------+--------+----------+
|   11 |      44|      20.0|
|   23 |    dsad|       9.0|
|   231|    temp|      21.0|
+------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Consider adding some more explainatiory text regarding the answer.

Comment: I wonder should
```val groupByUserWinFun = Window.partitionBy("userid")```
be
```val groupByUserWinFun = Window.partitionBy("userid","useid1/2")```
? since the score is for each pair.

Answer (score 1):

Group by will work:

```
val original = Seq(
  (23, null, "dsad", 3),
  (11, "44", null, 4),
  (231, null, "temp", 5),
  (231, null, "temp", 2)
).toDF("userid", "useid1", "userid2", "score")

// action
val result = original
  .withColumn("useid1/2", coalesce($"useid1", $"userid2"))
  .withColumn("score", $"score" * when($"useid1".isNotNull, 5).otherwise(3))
  .groupBy("userid", "useid1/2")
  .agg(sum("score").alias("final score"))

result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------+--------+-----------+
|userid|useid1/2|final score|
+------+--------+-----------+
|23    |dsad    |9          |
|231   |temp    |21         |
|11    |44      |20         |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

`coalesce` will do the needful.

```
df.withColumn("userid1/2", coalesce(col("useid1"), col("useid1")))
```

basically this function return first non-null value of the order

**documentation :**

```
COALESCE(T v1, T v2, ...)

Returns the first v that is not NULL, or NULL if all v's are NULL.
```

needs an import `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.coalesce`

Comment: How do you multiply by 3 or 5 depending on the null column in this case (second part of the question)?